# Шаблонные структуры с наследованием и переопределенными методами

Tags: c++, наследование

Есть две шаблонные структуры `List` и `SinglyList`.

В самой структуре есть внутренняя структура `Node`(тк мне нужно чтобы о структуре Node знали только List и его наследники)

Так же есть функция `push_back`(в будущем будет еще парочку).

И в каждом классе наследнике структура `Node`, функция `push_back`, и функция `getNode` будет разной.

Вот пример List.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H
template<typename T>
struct List {
protected:
    struct Node;
private
    virtual Node* getNode(const int index) = 0;
    int p_size;
public:
    int size() { return p_size; }

    virtual void push_back(const T data) = 0;

    T& operator[](const int index) {
        return getNode(index)->data;
    }
};

#endif //LIST_H
```

И SinglyList.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef SINGLYLIST_H
#define SINGLYLIST_H
#include "List.h"
template<typename T>
struct SinglyList : public List<T> {
public:
    List<T>::Node* head;
    struct List<T>::Node{
        Node() {
            cout << "constructor" << endl;
        }
    }
    List<T>::Node* getNode(const int index) override {
        List<T>::Node* prev = new List<T>::Node(10);
        return prev;
    }
    void push_back(const T data) {
        cout << "push_back method" << endl;
    }
};
#endif //SINGLYLIST_H
```

Так же в будущем будет структура `DoublyList`

В которой будет переменная `Node* head;` и `Node* tail;` и так же другой конструктор с функциями.

Тот код, который я привел очевидно не работает. Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать то что мне нужно. Желательно закрепить свой ответ простым кодом, так же можно посоветовать сайт, на котором я могу подробней почитать об этой теме.

Мне все это нужно чтобы я мог передавать в функцию передавать `List` и на выходе получать например vector или массив. Что-то типа функции `toArray` или `toVector` а эта функция будет у всех структур наследников одинаковая.

**Дополнение:**

Вот примерно так я представляю структуру.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно по картинке в структуре есть похожие структуры Node, переменные p_size(на картинке я забыл ее добавить) и функции на пример getNode.

Вот я и захотел вынести все похожее в абстрактную структуру.

А насчет toVector я представлял себе это так. Есть функция

```
vector<T> toVector(List<T> list){
    vector<T> vec;
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
        vec.push_back(list[i]);
    return vec;
}
```

Comment: Не понятно чего вы хотите добиться. Пожалуйста, поясните подробней последний абзац.

Comment: @Cerdo ну как еще объяснить. Я хочу сделать функцию конвертирования из списков в массивы или вектор.

Comment: Реализуйте индексный оператор [] и функцию size() для обоих контейнеров, и будет работать ваша функция конвертации. Вот только при чем тут Node  вы так и не объяснили.

Comment: @Cerbo ну емае. Node - это элемент списка. У обычного списка элементы имеют указать на следующий только. А в двойном списке еще и на предыдущий. И я в курсе что [] и size() реализовать надо. Но я не могу тк мне в абстрактном классе List надо указать что в каждой структуре наследнике есть структура Node и ее реализация разная. Это надо чтобы я мог вынести функцию getNode() а следовательно и [] ну и size() там же будет. Проблема только с Node. В абстрактном классе я хочу чтоб было показано что есть структура Node а в наследниках ее реализация разная.

Comment: @Cerbo ну я же код еще скинул. Но он не рабочийтк я не знаю что делать. И основной вопрос не в функции конвертации. А в объединении всех списков

Answer (score 0):

Класс(структура), это некая инструкция компилятору о том, какими должны быть экземпляры этого типа и что они могуть сделать.  Если в классе вы объявили о новом типе сущности( Node), то вы должны определять что она из себя представляет, но не  в другой сущности(в данном случаи в наследнике). Класс(структура) не является пространством имен, чтобы взять и в любом другом классе(структуре) определить тип, принадлежащий другому типу. Нужно написать хоть какое то определение `Node` в абстрактном классе(можно с пустым телом), а в производном классе написать(если хотите) производную от него структуру. Также нельзя оставлять неинициализированным  члены (в данном случаи `p_size`). Например, можно так:

```
template<typename T>
struct List {
protected:
    struct Node {
        T data{};
    };

    virtual Node* getNode(const int index) = 0;
private:   
    int p_size{};
public:
    int size() { return p_size; }

    virtual void push_back(const T data) = 0;

    T& operator[](const int index) {
        return getNode(index)->data;
        p_size = index;
    }
    virtual ~List() {};
};

template<typename T>
struct SinglyList : public List<T> {
public:
    struct Node : List<T>::Node {
        Node() {            
            cout << "constructor" << endl;
        }
    };
    //это уже SinglyList::Node
    Node* getNode(const int index) override {
        return new Node[index];        
    }
    void push_back(const T data) {
        cout << "push_back method" << endl;
    }
};
```

Но, это не то, что вам нужно, и то, что вы написали, это какая то смесь, из чего строить что то осмысленное, пока невозможно. Для получения желаемого результата,  методы класса  должны  иметь определенную смысль, члены класса должны  инициализироваться определенным значением. Так что доработайте классы. Также  подумайте о смысле этой иерархии, потому что, для окончательной цели(передать один контейнер, а на выходе иметь другой), вам не нужно прибегнуть к наследованию, тем самым увеличивая и время выполнения и размеры обьектов.  Пусть ваша функция сама будет шаблоном, который  принимает  один контейнер, копирует данные в другой контейнер, и вернет его, где параметры шаблона есть типы этих контейнеров.

Comment: Я дополнил вопрос. И надеюсь все понятно объяснил.

Answer (score 0):

Варианты решения

1. Обычный полиморфизм

```
     template<typename T>
     struct SingleDirectionNode
     {
         T Data;
         SingleDirectionNode * Next;
         bool moveForward();
     };

     template<typename T>
     struct DoubleDirectionNode: SingleDirectionNode<T>
     {
        DoubleDirectionNode * Previouse;
        bool modeBackward();
     };
```

2. Статический полиморфизм

```
     template<typename T>
     struct SingleDirectionNode
     {
         T Data;
         SingleDirectionNode * Next;
     };

     template<typename T>
     struct DoubleDirectionNode
     {
        T Data;
        SingleDirectionNode * Next;
        DoubleDirectionNode * Previouse;
     }

     template<typename N>
     bool Forward(N *& node)
     {
         node = node ? node->Next : nullptr;
         return nullptr != node;
     }

     template<typename N>
     bool Backward(N *& node)
     {
         node = node ? node->Previouse : nullptr;
         return nullptr != node;
     }
```

Comment: Честно не очень понял, что вы написали. Вопрос не в этом. Вы понимаете, что я могу написать так. В структуре `SinglyList` внутренняя структура `Node` с `T data` и `Node* pNext`. Так же все функции и тд. И так же отдельно `DoublyList` со всем своим, но Я ХОЧУ ПОХОЖИЙ ФУНКЦИОНАЛ ВЫНЕСТИ В АБСТРАКТНУЮ СТРУКТУРУ. И там и там есть Node только разная и там и там есть функция getNode и так же по разному реализована. Так же другие функции название одно, а реализация разная. А уже потом принимать в функции абстрактную структуру и выдавать вектор.

Comment: Хотя я могу так же сделать функцию toArray в каждой структуре и проблем не будет по факту, но эти функции даже реализацию одинаковую имеют. И если я буду все писать, как я объяснил выше. Это столько копипаста будет если я например еще CircleList добавлю.